# Spring Boot's datasource auto-configuration issue in Integration tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, integration-testing

I try to change from `application.properties` to `application.yml`. My Spring Boot application starts and works fine, but all of integration test cases are failing.

This is error message at console log

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::       (v1.5.10.RELEASE)

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

 Description:

Field datasource in com.example.core.config.ServiceConfig 
required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' in your configuration.
```

Although I defined datasource in file `application.yml` and it works fine  while running Spring boot app ... yet fails when running test cases, either via intelliJ runner or via Gradle -build task.

here are my configs:

```
spring:
  profiles: default
  datasource:
    hikari:
          minimum-idle: 1
          maximum-pool-size: 5
          pool-name: yourPoolName
          auto-commit: false
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://xxx
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
    maximumPoolSize: 5
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource

---
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    hikari:
          minimum-idle: 1
          maximum-pool-size: 5
          pool-name: yourPoolName
          auto-commit: false
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://xxx
    username: xx
    password: xx
    maximumPoolSize: 5
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

in my test class I tried everything :

```
@SpringBootTest also 
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ServiceConfig.class, ApplicationConfig.class},initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
```

nothing seems to help.. 
runing test seems to ignore aapplication.yml completely

applicationConfig

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    /**
     *  Total customization - see below for explanation.
     */
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @PostConstruct
    private void inti () {
       String [] ps =  this.environment.getActiveProfiles();
        for (String p : ps) {

            System.out.println("Currrent profile is "+p);
        }
    }


    @Autowired
    DataSource datasource;

    @Bean
    public DataSourceTransactionManager transactionManager() throws SQLException {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
    }
    @Bean
    public SqlSessionFactory mySqlSessionFactory() throws Exception {
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(datasource);
        return sessionFactory.getObject();
    }
```

here is one of my test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {  ApplicationConfig.class})
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class OrdersServiceTest {


    @Autowired
    OXUserDetailsService ous;

    @Autowired
    OXOrderServices ors;


    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

    }


    @Test
    public void testgetMyOrders() {
        OXUser ou = ous.getUserById(1);

        OXCustomer c = ors.showOrderForUser(ou);
        Assert.assertNotNull(c);
    }

    @Test
    public void testgetOrderItemsByOrderId() {
        List<OXOrderItem> ous =ors.getOrderItemsByOrderId(1);
        Assert.assertNotNull(ous);
    } }
```

spring version I use is 5.0.4 and below is relative boot dependencies  have :

```
dependencies {
...
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:1.3.1')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile group: 'org.hamcrest', name: 'hamcrest-library', version:'1.3'
    testCompile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version:'2.2.0'
    testCompile 'org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.19'
}
```

am I missing some spring boot magic config? why is it failing on test cases?

Comment: You should post the content of file `ApplicationConfig.java`. If testing work require another Java-based config file, let's post its content.

Comment: I don't think application.config is relevant here but sure.. I have edited and posted that as well...

Comment: Can you check, whether you have the same application.yml in src/main/resources and src/test/resources?

Comment: I don’t have application.yml file at all in stc/test/resources

Answer (score 0):

**(1)** File `application.yml`, Add these lines

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  datasource:
    hikari:
          minimum-idle: 1
          maximum-pool-size: 5
          pool-name: yourPoolName
          auto-commit: false
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://xxx
    username: xxx
    password: xxx
    maximumPoolSize: 5
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
```

By delcaring line `profiles: test`, Spring Boot is auto-configuration for testing.

(2) File `OrdersServiceTest.java`

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class OrdersServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    OXUserDetailsService ous;

    @Autowired
    OXOrderServices ors;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {

    }

    @Test
    public void testgetMyOrders() {
        OXUser ou = ous.getUserById(1);
        OXCustomer c = ors.showOrderForUser(ou);
        Assert.assertNotNull(c);
    }

    @Test
    public void testgetOrderItemsByOrderId() {
        List<OXOrderItem> ous = ors.getOrderItemsByOrderId(1);
        Assert.assertNotNull(ous);
    }

}
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing (supports auto-configuration for tests)

Comment: unfortunately your suggestion does not work. anyone else please?

Answer (score 0):

You might have extra-spaces in `yml` file,

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  datasource:
    hikari:
          minimum-idle: 1
          maximum-pool-size: 5
          pool-name: yourPoolName
          auto-commit: false
```

Would this work instead?

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  datasource:
    hikari:
      minimum-idle: 1
      maximum-pool-size: 5
      pool-name: yourPoolName
      auto-commit: false
```